# App is not installed using react native command

Tags: ios, react-native

I have react native cli application and when I tried to run it on simulator using `npx react-native run-ios` command it builds app successfully, bundler gets started and it shows 100% complete of bundler process but on simulator app is not being installed.

Note: simulator opens automatically but app not installed. When I use Xcode to run app it is working fine

Can you please help me with this.

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18P68U_GYLdLyzCU6-Yy4hM3z2FoKvRGF/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: run "adb devices" to get list of devices attached, or connect your phone with usb cable and run your project in your phone with "npx react-native run-ios"

Comment: I want to run ios simulator but it builds it sucessfully metro bundler bendes JS but app is not being install on simulator(virtual iPhone device) and if I am not wrong adb only useful for Emulators(Android virtual device)

Comment: One thing I observe that it always open same simulator even if I specify simulator name and the destination id Witten in command line is different that simulator open. I am assuming that destination id is the id of simulator

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it working by clearing all cash using DevCleaner(From app store) also deleted all core simulators and added few again. I specified name of simulator as well with command as `npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11"`

Comment: Still causes same issue with `sudo`, without sudo it works only :(